# how to call rows properly from MYSQL database into HTML table

Tags: php, html

I have a form that a user fills in to add information into a mysql table.

Now when i try display the table i get

```
ID  Name Phone
-   -    -
```

a very thin line is appearing under the table headers. I checked my sql table. the information did go into the table but it isnt displaying it properly? Maybe I need to set my table height or something?

Heres my list.php code:

```
<table border = 3><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Extension</th><th>Phone</th><th>Department</th></tr>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif}
-->
</style>

<?php
include('database.php');

$query="SELECT * FROM users";
$rez=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rez))
{
    print "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td>
            <td>{$row['name']}</td>
            <td>{$row['email']}</td>
            <td>{$row['extension']}</td>
            <td>{$row['phone']}</td>
            <td>{$row['department']}</td></tr>"

}
$this_Stud_ID = MYSQL_RESULT($rez,$row,"id");

?>
</table>
<br> <br>
<a href="search.php">Search</a>
<br>
<a href="add.php">Add</a>
<br>
<a href="delete.php"> Delete </a> 
<br>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a> 
</h3>
```

Comment: have you checked the developers console and confirmed that the text is actually being outputted?

Comment: Why are you adding a style in the body and come to that inside a table tag when the stype applies to the page `<body>` which we have to hope appeared abobe this code

Comment: If you can see your code, ___Its more likely you can debug your code___

Comment: What happened to the rest of the `print` inside the while loop???

Comment: This line `$this_Stud_ID = MYSQL_RESULT($rez,$row,"id");` wont work AFTER you have consumed all your result set in the while loop

Comment: i fixed the missing while loop @RiggsFolly. Is there fix you would reccomend sir?

Comment: The _stealth edit_ was fun, but you still do not have a properly formed table row!

Comment: my apologese im still learning. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Table rows end with a `</tr>`

Comment: look in your PHP error log. There should be plenty in there for you to be getting on with.

Comment: I'll try. no idea where that is. Thank you for your help sir. I do apologise if this was a silly question.

Comment: there's a quote missing in your `while` block. and you didn't echo `$this_Stud_ID`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i fixed the quote but what do you mean echo sir?

Comment: `<td>{$row['department']}</td></tr>";` missing semi-colon. As for the `$this....` it's just an assigned variable, I don't see you doing anything with it. In any case, use php's error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to sort out the obvious errors in the HTML.

Comment: Why is there a style block inside of a table? That is a first.

Comment: Stop using MySQL and use `MySQLi_` or  `PDO` functions instead, MySQL_ is ***DEPRECATED*** in PHP 5 and **REMOVED** in PHP7. Stop using it. Now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mysqli instead of mysql for security reasons

make sure the problem in not in your Database.php , a basic working model :

```
$Mydatabase = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') 
    or Exit('Could not connect to server.' );

mysql_select_db('mydb', $Mydatabase) 
    or Exit('Could not select database.');
```

> - change '***username***' and '***password***'
>   and change '***mydb***' to the name of your database

then in your index page change the necessary values to connect to the (`database.php`) file we made before 
 **Basic Example** :

```
<?php

include('database.php');

$query   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users" , $Mydatabase);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   // << fill your table here  >>

}
```